# Sun Bathing to get Vitamin D for infants

Tags: infant, sunlight

Is sun bathing still recommended option to get natural vitamin D for infants or one should prefer the medications like Vit D3, calcitrol etc.
Also which sunlight morning time or afternoon time is most beneficial?

Comment: In Australia, this would be a definite NO. The risk of skin cancer is far too high.

Comment: I remember reading that you need only 15 minutes of sunlight on your face to get the Vitamin D you need. There is no need for sunbathing. If you do not go out, or always put sunscreen or a hat on the baby, use a supplement. If you are out without sunscreen for a short time each day, you're fine. Sun bathing without sunscreen is a no, for skin cancer reasons.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are significant differences between individuals. I'm a pasty red head, my wife is mediterranean. My vitamin D levels are fine whereas hers a very low and she has to take supplements. Our son (who's a lot darker than me) is also lacking in vitamin D. Blood tests are simple and (in Australia) free - so it might be worth getting a baseline test done if you are concerned (liver function, sugar levels, vitamin D, iron, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

While getting Vitamin D is important, remember that how you get it is important, too.  Sunlight has other characteristics.

But, I am not a Dr, so let me share a pretty comprehensive site that covers this in detail: http://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminD-HealthProfessional/

After reading that, you will most likely know more than you ever wanted. :)

EDIT:

Importantly, the sun section concludes with this:

> Assessment of vitamin D requirements cannot address the level of sun
>   exposure because of these public health concerns about skin cancer,
>   and there are no studies to determine whether UVB-induced synthesis of
>   vitamin D can occur without increased risk of skin cancer.